# What is the best way to bind PhoneGap events (like backbutton) to views in ember.js

Tags: cordova, ember.js

I'm playing with PhoneGap and emberjs (trying to build "proof of concept" mobile/HTML5 application based on ember.js).

Ember.js itself works fine, but I haven't found any good way to "bind" PhoneGap events to views.

For instance, I would like to handle backbutton event and remove a view on it. It would be nice to define behavior in view class and call document.addEventListener when instance of the view is appended and call document.removeEventListener when view instance removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like that on SC2.0 [gist](https://gist.github.com/1376360).

Take a look at the [event dispatcher](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js)  to see how to add custom delegate events on views.

It should not be much difficult to inject this at the app start routine.

I hope it helps you.